# Titulo en react admin aparece cómo undefined

Tags: javascript

estoy trabajando con react admin. Y estoy teniendo un problema con title del proyecto.
Les comparto una imágen de cómo se visualiza:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi app.js es:

```
import * as React from "react";

import { Admin, Resource} from "react-admin";

import { dataProvider } from "./myDataProvider";

//import dataProvider from "./myDataProvider";

//import userList from "./userList.js";

//import userEdit from "./userEdit.js";

import configEdit from "./configEdit";



import ReiniciarVmButton from './ReiniciarVmButton';



const App = () => (

  

  <Admin

   dataProvider={dataProvider}

  title="prueba"

   >  

  <Resource

      name="config"

      list={configEdit}

      options={{ label: "Configuración" }}  

    />

 <Resource name="reiniciarVM" list={ReiniciarVmButton} options={{ label: "Reiniciar Equipo" }} />

  </Admin>



);



export default App;
```

Aparentemente está tomando el valor de "options"
Pero si clickeo en reiniciar Equipo aparece cómo vacío, entonces no comprendo bien, cómo funciona.
Porbé añadirle al componente admin title="prueba" pero no modifica nada.
Al margen de todo esto.
Si estoy parado en configuración el titulo se muestra cómo: Configuración #undefined
No entiendo de dónde sale el undefined.

Desde ya, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo arreglé estableciendo en configEdit un título.

```
const configEdit = (props) => (

  <Edit {...props} title="Configuración">
```